# Php truncate big data

Tags: buffer, long-integer, apache2.4, php

I was working on an API returning data as `application/json` but my 
`echo json_encod($array);` was never completely sent to the client so I struggled a lot trough the functions to discover that also a basic page with `phpinfo()` is sent only by half to the client.

The charging symbol in the browser remain active as it's charging and dev tools say `CAUTION: request is not finished yet`
After some minutes in the console log appear `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)` with no change in the page.

You can see what I'm talking about at http://213.209.253.6:7209/info.php

I tried with multiple suggestion of change in .htaccess or php.ini or in the page.

- set the content-type in the header page
- set x-Accel-Buffering: no in the header page
- output_buffering Off
- set max_input_vars
- ob_flush()/ob_end_clean()
- setting compression with moule_deflate

(Yes I always restarted apache and yes I changed the right php.ini)
ENV:

- Apache 2.4.37 (built on my own)
- Php 7.0.33 (built on my own)
- Debian 8 i686
- Test API on Chrome 71 and Firefox 64

EDIT
Actually this problem exist only when I contact the page from my internal Network. I'm behind a natting router and the port 7209 is mapped on a PC also in my internal Network. I tried and with another connection I display data normally...

Comment: The link loads perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Probably your router is configured for the wrong package size and the chunks are too big. You ISP could shorten them. Please that out

Comment: i've not access rights on my router (i can only commit my requests to my ISP) and my ISP answered me that thay cannot check that for me... yes their customer care service is pretty useless... i arounded the problem using the internal network ip when make requests from inside and the public ip when from outside